# Alter table add column is anything else needed

Tags: sql-server-2008

HI I added a column to the table with just this, do i need to add anything else? I have seen our previous consultant add more with same data type 
but regrettably I did not note that.

ALTER TABLE ZRS.PMAPS

ADD COUNTY nvarchar(MAX)

Comment: How about whether the field can be null? Also, is this going to be part of a changescript that is rolled out into production? If so, you probably want a transaction scope...

Comment: Have you tried your query? What research have you done on this yourself?

Comment: You might consider an index on County if you're going to be querying on that often.

Comment: Nulls allowed, thanks

Answer (score 0):

while adding a new column in to a table  with alter.
the column must be null. else it will raise an error.
nothing required along with u'r syntax if u wanna add constraint.